# Disappearing Calendar Tasks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, outlook-web-access

I have a user using Outlook 2013/Office 365. For some reason he is not able to see calendar tasks before 5 months ago(example he is able to see task from today March 10, 2015 to November 2014, But he can not go further back).He does not manually delete any of his calendar tasks. A we have move everything over to the cloud about a year ago. I have looked at both outlook 2013 and OWA calendar but was unable to find any of his calendar tasks before November. So my question is how would I be able to find/recover these task that disappeared?

Comment: Is this affecting other users in the same way, or just this one user? Are any retention rules in place on the Exchange server?

Comment: Techie007 I myself use both outlook/OWA, an I am able to go back about two an see my calendar tasks. Also I have not heard anyone else in the company complain about this issue. There are no retention rule on the exchange server.

Comment: Has the user set auto archive settings to move old items from the calendar?

Comment: Techie007 I have made a mistake the retention rule is up to 6 months then archived on the exchange server. CharlieRB no the user has not touched the auto archive settings.